# Collapse all Folders on directories tab in SmartSVN Foundation

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, smartsvn

Is there any way to Collapse all folder on the Directories Tab in SmartSVN Foundation 8.0.1?

I Accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Select All) and ALL THE FOLDERS COLLAPSED!

Now if i want to add a specific folder i need to collapse some or all... or most, but there's no easy way to do it, right now i'm doing it one by one, but the vendor folder (all composer packages) is enormous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd. I've tried to replicate this and have been unable (I'm assuming you're on Windows?) even if I select all and then click the collapse icon on one folder it just collapses that folder.

More than happy to raise a feature request for you if you could give me a bit more detail about what you're after? For example, adding a 'collapse/expand all' and/or a 'collapse/expand selected' option to the View menu that you could set a custom shortcut for in the Edit -> Customize -> Accelerators options?

Comment: Yeah, i'm using "Windows 7 SP1", and i guess it should be an obvious feature since repositories directories have way too much depth... but yeah.
And the problem didn't happen selecting them all with Shift or Ctrl + click, it was with the focus on the Directories tab and then the "OS Keyboard shortcut" to select all (Ctrl + A on English or Ctrl + E on Spanish)
The problem was to close ALL folders, not only the root folder, of course if i close the root folder everything goes in... but it sucks if i try to look for a specific folder, the scroll bar is ginormous. Every folder keeps it's state.

Comment: Well, they're not always that deep - it depends on what's in the working copy and the repository (though it's the working copy that SmartSVN will be displaying rather than the repository), and also how big the working copy is. Sounds to be honest like it might help to split out some folders from your working copy into different repositories, if that's possible?

Whether it is or not though I'll raise the feature request for you.

Comment: Please do so... and yeah, thank you for the advice on separating the folders in different repositories that could help with storing storing dependencies (I know they should not be stored and use a "Dependency/Packet Manager" like Composer in my case or NPM or whatever it is).